# Call Applet methods from outside the browser

Tags: java, javascript, security, applet

Here's the overall flow of the use case:

1. User navigates to page with a third party applet
2. Another program sees that the browser URL has changed and fires a custom Java app that I have written.
3. That custom app needs to be able to call methods on the Applet

Is it possible to call the Applet from an application outside of the browser?

I've seen lots of questions and answers around calling applets from JS in the page, but that not the case here. That being said, however, if it were possible to inject JS into the page at runtime and have THAT make the call to the applet, that might be a workaround.

Comment: This sound both malevolent and (fortunately) impractical.  So I guess, from a security POV, no.

Comment: Actually its for security; Password Managers (ie Citrix and Oracle) remember and auto submit credentials for the user so that they don't have to remember them or worse, write them down on a piece of paper. More generally I'm not sure how code from outside the sandbox calling code in the sandbox would be considered malevolent; regardless that's not the case here.